# Trying to alter a short program to use pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I just started learning about pointers this week, and I'm having trouble with a lab assignment. I am given program and have to alter it to use pointers for the variables old and new. (code is linked at the bottom of this post)

I've attempted it, but I'm quite confused and ran into a couple of problems:

1) My values aren't being entered into the right index.

2) I get a segmentation fault when I try to add my 3rd value. I know this occurs when I try to access memory that I do not have access to, so my pointers are going wrong somewhere.

Any kind of guidance would be much appreciated!

The original working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARSZ 10

typedef unsigned int UINT;

void showData(int [], UINT, UINT, int, int);

int main(void){

   int array[ARSZ] = {0};                 
   UINT old = ARSZ-1, new = ARSZ-1;        
   int runningTot = 0, maxAveLen, curAveLen = 1, newVal, numCtr=0;

   printf("Enter the maximum number of values to average over: ");
   scanf("%d", &maxAveLen);

   while(1){

      runningTot -= array[old];            // subtract value pointed to by old
      old += ((++numCtr) >= maxAveLen);    // increment old if maxAveLen inputs
      old %= ARSZ;                         // wraps old to 0 if array sz exceeded

      printf("Enter new value to array:"); // get new value to add to array
      scanf("%d", &newVal);       

      new = (++new)%ARSZ;                  // increment new reset to 0 if >= ARSZ
      runningTot += (array[new] = newVal); // add new Value at [new] location

      // Determine the number of values to average over i.e. 1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4...
      curAveLen = (numCtr >= maxAveLen)?maxAveLen:numCtr;
      showData(array, old, new, runningTot, curAveLen);

   }
}

// Display the current data
void showData(int ar[], UINT O, UINT N, int RT, int aveLen){ 

      for (int i=0; i < ARSZ; i++)         // Print out the array contents    
         printf("%d\t", ar[i]);

         printf("\nOld = %u, \tNew = %u, \tTotal = %d, \tAve = %5.2f\n\n", 
     O, N, RT, (float)RT/aveLen);

}
```

My broken code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARSZ 10

typedef unsigned int UINT;

void showData(int [], UINT*, UINT*, int, int);

int main(void){

   int array[ARSZ] = {0};                  
   UINT *old = &array[ARSZ-1], *new = &array[ARSZ-1];      
   int runningTot = 0, maxAveLen, curAveLen = 1, newVal, numCtr=0;

   printf("Enter the maximum number of values to average over: ");
   scanf("%d", &maxAveLen);

   while(1){

      runningTot -= array[*old];            
      *old += ((++numCtr) >= maxAveLen);    
      *old %= ARSZ;                         

      printf("Enter new value to array:"); 
      scanf("%d", &newVal);       

      *new = *(++new)%ARSZ;                  // Error might be occurring here
      runningTot += (array[*new] = newVal); 

      curAveLen = (numCtr >= maxAveLen)?maxAveLen:numCtr;
      showData(array, old, new, runningTot, curAveLen);

   }
}

// Display the current data
void showData(int ar[], UINT *O, UINT *N, int RT, int aveLen){ 

      for (int i=0; i < ARSZ; i++)            
         printf("%d\t", ar[i]);
      printf("\nOld = %u, \tNew = %u, \tTotal = %d, \tAve = %5.2f\n\n",
     *O, *N, RT, (float)RT/aveLen);

}
```

Comment: Please post the code here on this site, and point out where you are getting the error.

Comment: Done. I'm actually not sure where the error is happening (I'm new to pointers so I could have errors in multiple areas), but I ran it through ddd and it SEEMS like its happening where I put the comment.

Comment: In the original code, `new = (++new)%ARSZ;` causes undefined behaviour, prior to C11.  I'd suggest changing it in case your compiler is not compliant with the new rules. (I guess you meant `new = (new + 1) % ARSZ;`

Comment: Your modified code is completely messed up. At the start it looks as if you want to change `old` and `new` frrom being array indices to using pointers into the array directly, but in the rest of your code you dereference the pointer and then use the result as an array index. For example in the orginal `old += ((++numCtr) >= maxAveLen)` changes which element we are operating on; but `*old += ((`... stays pointing at the same element and modifies the value stored in that element . It might help if you try and describe in words what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: I'd also suggest changing the variable names of `old` and `new` (e.g. `p_old` and `p_new` ) to avoid confusion between the two versions

Comment: Hi Matt,

Thanks for replying. I am trying to use old and new as direct pointers into the array. I want to move the pointer for new to the next index whenever I am adding a new value. I want the pointer for old to move up if the number of values I've entered is >= maxAveLen. I also want both new and old to wrap around to the first index once I've reached the end of the array. I only want to use the value stored in new or old when I'm adding or subtracting from runningTot.

Answer (score 1):

These are not equivalent

`UINT *old = &array[ARSZ-1], *new = &array[ARSZ-1];        // ...but only to initialize pointers`

`UINT old = ARSZ-1, new = ARSZ-1;        // ...but only to initialize pointers`

You cannot make a pointer to a constant. What you could do is allocate memory for the "old" and "new" using either malloc() or by assigning it an address
of another valid UINT. Then you could assign a constant.

This is wrong too:
`*new = *(++new)%ARSZ;                  // increment new reset to 0 if >= ARSZ`
 You are incrementing the the pointer itself rather than the value inside the pointer. Try this:

`*new = (++*new)%ARSZ;`